# Colorama on Python, Windows 10 - after adding init(autoreset=True) colors disappear

Tags: python, colorama

I am new to Python and I'm trying to create some custom git hook that adds coloring to console messages.

Unfortunately when I add `init(autoreset=True)`, the coloring stops working. Without that line code, it works but I'd like to set auto-resetting. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.18363), Python 3.9.2, Colorama 0.4.4

```
from colorama import init, Fore
init(autoreset=True) # <----

def main():
    print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
    print('\033[31m' + "red text")
    print("some not red text")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As a workaround I reset inline text:

```
print(f'text {Fore.RED} some red text {Style.RESET_ALL}!')
```

Comment: On my Win10/Py3.9 your code works and draws two lines of red text and one white.

Comment: Thanks for checking so fast. I also checked my python version. 3.9.2.

Comment: So does your Python 3.9.2 works with this code? Which Python version doesn't work then?

Comment: No, with that version I commented, it is not working for me.

Comment: Try doing `python -m pip install --upgrade colorama` maybe it helps.

Comment: Sadly it doesn´t. :(

Comment: Can you also explain in what way "it doesn't work"? What do you see on console screen?

Comment: Without init(autoreset=True) all lines are red. With it all lines are white. No errors.

Comment: Cannot replicate. What OS are you on? What version of python? What version of colorama?

Comment: Actually I have Python 3.9.1 and you have 3.9.2. On my 3.9.1 it works, on yours it doesn't. So at least this difference in pythons may cause the difference in outputs.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I've updated my question with version details.

Comment: I have python 3.9.2 on Windows 10 and your code prints red text on one line followed by white text on the next line. Are you running from a Command Prompt or from your IDE?

Comment: https://ibb.co/w76j8nb

Comment: @JustinEzequiel git commit is triggering the pre-commit hook (the file with my python code in it) from .git/hooks folder of my project. I did try executing git commit from git bash and also cmd. Same result. (When removing init(..) it is coloring both consoles)

Comment: @DávidSzékely Maybe you can add a screenshot of what you see on the screen (that would help: better than some details burrowed in the thread of comments. Also, when you say "it does not work", are you trying with that very example you give? (meaning, not with the real code that you might try to implement)